# How to get multiple values from checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 framework.

Using a query to get values from the table in and display it in the checkbox, but when I select more than one it just displays single, not multiple.

This is Blade PHP code with query.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Students:</strong>
        <div style="margin-top: 5px" >
        
        <?php  $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'rp') or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select users.id, users.name from users, model_has_roles where model_has_roles.model_id=users.id and model_has_roles.role_id=14;
");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              unset($id, $name);
              $id = $row['id'];
              $name = $row['name']; 
              echo '<form><input type=checkbox name="student_id[]"  value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</form>'; }

//echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";?>
```

He is my function code in Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Ticket $ticket){
     request()->validate([
        'gpname' => 'required',
        'detail' => 'required',
        'semester' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        
       // 'status',
       // 'Assigned',
        ]);

      $users= Auth::user();
      $rr= $users->roles->pluck('name')->toArray();
        // dd($users->id);
   // $data= $request->all();
     //$ticket = new Ticket;
     if($rr[0]=='Admin'){ 

        $data= $request->all();
       //dd($data['Assigned'])    ;
       $ticket->gpname=$data['gpname'];
        $ticket->detail=$data['detail'];
        $ticket->semester=$data['semester'];
        $ticket->gender=$data['gender'];
        //dd("hhh");
        $student_id = array("student_id");
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if(!empty($_POST['student_id'])){
                $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
                foreach($student_id as $id){
                   // echo $id.'<br/>';
                   dd($data['student_id']);
                }
            }
        }
      dd($data['student_id']);



       //dd( $data['student_id[]']);
        //$ticket->studentnames=$users->empid;
        $ticket->user_id=$users->id;
        
        
        //$ticket->Assigned=$data['Assigned'];
        $ticket->save();
```

and as you see if I make `dd($data['student_id']);` as a comment it's never going to the previous one inside `foreach()`

How I can get multiple values from the checkbox?

Comment: Why are you using mysqli with Laravel?

Comment: because I'm using localhost xampp server

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. The server stack you are using has nothing to do with it. Don't use mysqli when using Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dd(); is killing the loop and returning only the first value you should echo your results instead of dd(); them or use.

```
if(!empty($_POST['student_id'])){
    $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
    $array_test = []
    foreach($student_id as $id){
       if($id == $data['student_id']){
            array_push($id, $array_test)
        } 
    }
    dd($array_test);
}
```

Since i don't know what are you trying to do so i will drop the second thought

```
if(!empty($_POST['student_id'])){
    $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
    $array_test = []
    foreach($student_id as $id){
        array_push($id, $array_test)
    }
    dd($array_test);
}
```